# Detect user clicked on specific button on mini browser (window phone)

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

Im on development of window phone application,

Scenario:
Mini browser opening a page(for example google.com)
Google.com has a button called 'Search'

```
If User clicked button 'Search'
  Redirect to an redirect.xaml
Else
  Do nothing
```

Here is my scenario, how can I actually detect the User clicked the button and only they can proceed to the next page? Is that I have to use javascript in this situation? because if on web, this is technique which I will use.

Answer (score 0):

Webbrowser control downloads we content and you have to parse the content or to handle the js actions. Thats the way to do it.

Comment: hmm, do you know any tutorial about this to make this clearer?